# android: get dimension of extended view using addOnGlobalLayoutListener but fails

Tags: android, view, oncreate, dimension

I am implementing the following `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` so as to measure the Extended View (doodleView) in main activity (A)'s `OnCreate` section.

```
  doodleView = (DoodleView) findViewById(R.id.doodleView);
  doodleView.setOnTouchListener(this);    

  doodleView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
  {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() 
        {
            doodleViewWidth = doodleView.getWidth(); 
            doodleViewHeight = doodleView.getHeight();
        }
  });
```

However, it underlines in red for the `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` with the following error statement:

```
The method addOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener) in the type ViewTreeObserver is not applicable for the arguments (new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){})
```

I have researched the web but cannot find a reason for the error. Would there be anyone knowing the problem? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: your import is wrong.

Comment: `doodleView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener....` would work without the correct import. Njzk is right

Comment: oh thanks i have just imported import android.view.ViewTreeObserver; but have not 
imported android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;  now the red error underlines are gone. Yet the doodleViewWidth and doodleViewHeight still returns as 0 as shown in the Toast.

Comment: would you like to post an answer for that?

Answer (score 1):

I was doing something very similar, but then I found onMeasure.  So if this is essentially a one time thing try doing something similar to this:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    View view = cardSlots[1];
    int cardHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
    int cardWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
    resizeView(playedSlot, cardWidth, cardHeight);
}

static public void resizeView(View view, int cardWidth, int cardHeight) {
    view.getLayoutParams().height = cardHeight;
    view.getLayoutParams().width = cardWidth;
    view.invalidate();
    //view.requestLayout();
    ((View)view.getParent()).invalidate();
}
```

This way you have less to worry about like doing this:

```
getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
```

which you may have forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I modified the function as

```
doodleView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
  {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() 
        {
            doodleViewWidth = doodleView.getWidth(); 
            doodleViewHeight = doodleView.getHeight();
        }
  });
```

all I have done is just added `ViewTreeObserver` class name before `OnGlobalLayoutListener()`.