# how to listen on ImageView VisibiltyChanged

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm trying to do something once the `setVisibility` function finish it's work, is there anyway that I can accomplish that? because `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` isn't what I need , and I can't find any method that allows me to!

Answer (score 0):

As see here:

[ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnGlobalLayoutListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)):

> Register a callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the
>   visibility of views within the view tree changes

So you can do it by adding `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` to `ImageView` like:

```
imageView.setTag(imageView.getVisibility());
....
@Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int visibility = imageView.getVisibility();
        if(Integer.parseInt(imageView.getTag()) != visibility)
        {
            // visibility changes...
        }
    }
 ....
```

Comment: @MixedCoder: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053630/android-get-dimension-of-extended-view-using-addongloballayoutlistener-but-fail how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one it will get triggered every time your layout changes

```
imageView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            Log.e("PRACTICE","VISIBILITY IS CHANGED");
        }
    });
```